# array length variable - c

Tags: c, arrays

i'm writing a c program and i've noticed that whenever i declare my array length with const variable(const size_t MAX_LEN  = *some number*) it sends me errors.
on the other hand, when i'm using (#define MAX_LEN = *some number*) as my array length declaration it works just fine.

the exact error i get : LinSeperator.c:45:2: error: variable length array ‘arr’ is used [-Werror=vla]
  double theAns, arr[MAX_LEN];
  ^

could anyone help me figure out why it happens?

EDIT: here's my code: 
this is my LinSeperatorHelperFunc.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

const size_t MAX_LEN = 199;

typedef struct Orange
{
double arr[MAX_LEN];
int tag;
}orange;


void learnProg(orange *o, double w[], int d);

void filePrinter(const char *output, FILE **fileIn, int d, double w[]);
```

this is my .c file:

```
#include "LinSeperator.h"
#include "LinSeperatorHelperFunctions.h"
#define NEG_ONE (-1)
#define NegToPos (2)




void LinSeperator(const char *In, const char *Out){
FILE * input;
orange o;
int d , pos, neg ,i , j;
//initializing the hypothesis vector as requested in step 1
double w[MAX_LEN];
for(i = 0 ; i<MAX_LEN ; i++){
    w[i] = 0;
}
input = fopen(In,"r");
if(input == NULL){
    printf("file doesnt exists");
    return;
}
fscanf(input, "%d %d %d", &d , &pos, &neg);

for(i = 0; i<pos+neg ; i++){
    o.tag = i<pos ? 1: -1;

    for(j = 0 ; j<d ; j++){
        fscanf(input, "%lf", &o.arr[j]);
        //removing ',' from being scanned
        if(j!= d-1){
            fgetc(input);
        }
    }
    learnProg(&o,w,d);
}
filePrinter(Out, &input, d, w);
fclose(input);

 }

void filePrinter(const char* out, FILE **in, int d, double w[]){
int i;
double theAns, arr[MAX_LEN];
FILE *output = fopen(out, "w");
if (output == NULL){
    printf("couldnt write to the current file");
    return;
}
while(!feof(*in)){

    for (i=0; i<d; i++) {
        fscanf((*in), "%lf", &arr[i]);
        if(feof(*in))//if we finished the checked vectors we should finish the file and the function 
        {
            fclose(output);
            return;
        }
        //preventing from reading the "," between each col
        if(i!=d-1){
            fgetc(*in);
        }
    }
    theAns=0;
    for (i=0; i<d; i++){
        theAns+=arr[i]*w[i];
    }
        //if ans >=0 print 1 to file else -1
    fprintf(output, "%d\n", NEG_ONE+NegToPos*(theAns>=0)); 
}
fclose(output);
  }




 //the learning progress algo
  void learnProg(orange *o, double w[], int d){
int i, negOrPos = (*o).tag;
double theAns = 0;
for(i = 0; i<d ; i++){
    theAns += ((*o).arr[i] * w[i]); //2.1
}
//has the same sign
if( (negOrPos * theAns) > 0 ){  //2.2
    return ;
}
else{
  for(i = 0; i<d ; i++){
      w[i] += (negOrPos * (*o).arr[i]);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And also include the *complete* error output?

Comment: try add `-std=c99` option.

Comment: Is your compiler working in compliance with c99 c standard? Because variable lenght arrays (VLAs) were only added in c99

Comment: Show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: "*`#define MAX_LEN = some number`*" most likely won't compile. You want to remove the `=`.

Answer (score 5):

In C, `const` do not create a compile-time constant. It merely creates a read only variable. The distinction is important.

When you use:

```
#define MAX_LEN 701
```

It's a directive given to the preprocessor to replace all
occurrences of `MAX_LEN` with `701`. When the compiler gets
your code, all it gets to see is the numerical constant.

C 90 standard allows to declare arrays with with numerical constant length only.
However, if you were to use C 99 you could use variable length arrays.

With `gcc`, you can use `--std=c99` or `--std=c90` to set what standard
to compile your code against.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the array is declared.

If it is declared at file scope (outside any function) then the array size must be a constant expression, like a `#define` raw number. Unfortunately C does not regard `const` variables as constant expressions.

If the array is declared at local scope, the problem is just that you are using a far too old compiler, or alternatively that you have misconfigured GCC. In case of GCC, tell it to compile your code according to the C standard language: `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a limitation of the language. You cannot use a const size_t in a array declaration. In example:

```
const size_t dimensions = 3;
size_t reality[dimensions]={3,8,12};
```

It won't compile, but

```
#define dimensions 3
size_t reality[dimensions]={3,8,12};
```

Works.

The sizes of statically-bounded arrays need to be constant expressions, and unfortunately in C that's only something like a literal constant or a sizeof expression or such like, but not a const-typed variable. You can try using [dynamic allocation of array of pointers](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation), but its more complicated to use.

As Lundin say, technically the standard C99 say that you cannot provide an initializer list to a VLA. Reference [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Initializing-Arrays).

Comment: The reason why the example doesn't compile is because you cannot provide an initializer list to a VLA. Overall, this answer is incorrect. In the year 1999 there was a new C standard.